# How to add country list in registration form in cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

I have simple registration form. I just want to add dropdown country list in registration form in cakephp. Please give me simple and detail description of what to do in all related files (like changes in module, controller and .ctp files). I have country list in my database table 'countries'.

In register.ctp i did this:
echo $form->input('country_id');

I am very new in cakephp, please help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In controller (make sure the column names are correct):

```
$this->loadModel('Country');
$this->set('countries', $this->Country->find('list',array('Country.id','Country.name')));
```

In view:

```
echo $form->input('country_id', array('options' => $countries));
```

Comment: This one is working correctly. Please let me know that how should i retrieve data from db and populate it here instead of manually adding countries

Comment: Happy's post shows how to fetch the countries from the database. You'll have to post your schema so we can make it match your fields names.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Find](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) to get a [List](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list) of all of your countries...

```
$this->set('countries', $this->Country->find('list',array('Country.id','Country.name')));
```

Then in your view use the [form helper](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#creating-form-elements) and pass your countries to it via the *options* parameter.

```
echo $this->Form->input('country_id', array('options'=>$countries));
```

Comment: I don´t know why its not working. When i put this set('countries', $this->Country->find('list',array('Country.id','Country.name'))); in users_controller.php it show me blank page

Comment: You may need to change exact field names to match yours, I just guessed you had a country id and a name? Switch on debugging to see your errors in app/Config/Core.php set debug level to 2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have correct id and name fields in country table, so its correct. But regarding the debug i couldn´t find it out in config folder, core.php.

Comment: Configure::write('debug', 2); - What version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: Wow, you should seriously upgrade :O I wouldn't even try developing further sorry ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use following syntax Just replace User model with appropriate model that you are using.

```
$this->set('countries',$this->User->Country->find('list'));
```